# Java ScheduledExecutorService behind the scenes

Tags: java, jvm

How does things like `scheduleAtFixedRate` work? How does it work behind the scenes and is there a penalty to using it?

More specifically, I have a task that I want to run periodically, say every 12 hours. The period is not strict at all, so my first instinct was to check in every request (tomcat server) if it's been more than >12 hours since the task last executed and if so, execute it and reset the timer. The downside of this is that I have to do a small time check on every request, make sure the task is run only once (using a semaphore or something similar) and the task might not execute in a long time if there's no requests.

`scheduleAtFixedRate` makes it easier to schedule a recurring task, but since I don't know how it does it, I don't know what the performance impact is. Is there a thread continually checking if the task is due to run? etc.

**edit:**
In `Timer.java`, there's a `mainLoop` function which, in my understanding, is something like this (overly simplified):

```
while(true) {
    currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if(myTask.nextExecutionTime == currentTime) myTask.run();
}
```

Won't this loop try to run as fast as possible and use a ton of CPU (I know, obviously not, but *why*)?  There's no Thread.sleep in there to slow things down.

Comment: Use a library like [quartz-scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) or similar. Or roll your own using `ScheduledExecutorService`.

Comment: "since I don't know how it does it" Look at the source code, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

You can read the code if you wish to work out how it works.

There is an overhead using ScheduledExecutorService in terms of CPU and memory, however on the scale of hours, minutes, second even milli-seconds, it probably not work worrying about.  If you have a task running in the range of micro-seconds, I would consider something more light weight.

In short, the overhead is probably too small for you to notice.  The benefit it gives you is ease of use, and it is likely to be worth it.

Comment: Another caveat is that the jdk's `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` implementation uses a synchronized queue. So while it makes a decent *scheduler* it would be a terrible idea to use it as dual-role *executor* due to lock contention when submitting tasks.

Comment: @the8472 you have to be submitting tasks at a high rate for this to matter. If you have one every hour, it won't.

Comment: If you do UDP networking and submit timeouts for example this can matter. Also, repeated tasks have to resubmit themselves, so even if you only submit them once they can still contend with the lock if you have a whole load of tasks popping on and off the work queue over multiple threads. Last but not least, STPE is also a normal Thread pool, if it is used as such (`execute()`/`submit()`) you also incur that overhead.